# Reordering rows of a dataframe in multiple columns in R

Tags: r, sorting

How can I re-order the rows of the dataframe df1 to have a dataframe like df2?

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1=c("h", "a", "n", "h", "a", "n", "h", "a", "n"), var2=c("e", "e", "e","f", "f", "f","v", "v", "v"))

df2 <- data.frame(var1=c("h", "h", "h", "a", "a", "a", "n", "n", "n"), var2=c("e", "f", "v","e", "f", "v","e", "f", "v"))
```

I need to specify values, so `desc` does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a dataframe by multiple column(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help

```
> df1[order(match(df1$var1, c("h", "a", "n"))), ]
  var1 var2
1    h    e
4    h    f
7    h    v
2    a    e
5    a    f
8    a    v
3    n    e
6    n    f
9    n    v
```